# Ventura OSX giving permission denied error on pod installing. SSH issue

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, macos-ventura

I have just upgraded my OSX to Ventura, And it started making my life hell. I have personal git server, usually we create ssh with `ssh-keygen` command. I created and provided the public to the server without keeping any password, Even I tried with password. But it always keep asking about password and give same error of permission denied. Can anyone have idea how to fix this?. Anyone went through this situation? I even can't get back my OSX version, So i need to find solution here...

Any help would be appreciated. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many methods, I came around generating the ssh with some other encryption method. like

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -d 521
```

And it worked like charm.

In Ventura OSX we need latest encryption method, So ecdsa is new RSA type encryption method that works.